# How to make Bootstrap columns act like table cells

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my bootstrap columns act like `td`s, or find some other way for them to have equal height and vertically centered text. I've tried doing the `display:table-cell` hack but to no success. What am I doing wrong below?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18560/

```
<div class="row like-table-row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      <p>
         Here's some text that will surely be long enough to go onto another line if I make it thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiisssssssssssssssssssssssss long
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <p>
           Here's some shorter text
       </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <p>
           Blah     
       </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row like-table-row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      <p>
         Here's some text
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <p>
           Here's some shorter text
       </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <p>
           Blah     
       </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.row.like-table-row { display: table-row; }
  .row.like-table.row > div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing everything right except removing the `float`. If you don't remove the float, it breaks the table layout.

```
.row.like-table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.row.like-table-row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float:none;
}
```

This should work just fine.

P.S. I used to use this technique a lot, but have stopped ever since the advent of **[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Correct method is to use `.row` as `table` and `.col-*` as `table-cell`.

```
.like-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.like-table > [class*=col-] {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

I have updated your fiddle to working demo. https://jsfiddle.net/rhythm19/DTcHh/33195/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in class name: .row.like-table-row > div. Now go ahead and remove floats to get the divs vertically centred. I updated your fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/vikasbaru/DTcHh/18566/

```
  .row.like-table-row > div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #000; float: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use vertical align you need a container that will have the vertical align property and an inner element to be aligned.

Basically you need three css rules:

```
.vertical-align {
  height: 150px; /* Height is important or it won't work */
  display: table-cell; /* We will give our div table cell property */
  vertical-align: middle; /* This will do the trick to center vertically inner element */
}
```

So your html will look like:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
  <div class="vertical-align">
    <p>Foo bar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mb3kyzgp/1/

If you need dynamic height, i suggest using jQuery to calculate tallest element, or you can set a height you think you won't reach (fast and easy but not the best).